# Issue with PG_CTL command in Macos -- Could not start server as FATAL: data directory "/Library/PostgreSQL/12/data" has wrong ownership

Tags: macos, network

I am unable to start the Postgres server and whenever I use pg_ctl I am getting the following error - can some one help me to fix this. I changed the folder permissions using CHmod and tried running with Sudo -s also but still the problem exists.

one error I did was, I deleted the Postmaster.pid when the server was running- post this I am getting this issue when ever I try to start the server through pg_ctl and another error when I use the pgadmin.

Any suggestions here will be really helpful- thanks.

Using Macos Shell command :

```
pg_ctl start -D /Library/PostgreSQL/12/data
waiting for server to start....2020-05-05 11:40:04.838 IST [1216] FATAL:  data directory "/Library/PostgreSQL/12/data" has wrong ownership
2020-05-05 11:40:04.838 IST [1216] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

Using pgadmin the error is as follows :

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5434? could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5434?
```

p.s. : I modified the hba.conf and also the postgres.conf files to allow connection from the local ip